# pytype -> ninja: error: dependency cycle:

Tags: python, types, static-analysis, ninja, pytype

I want to check the type using **pytype** on the below code.

```
import re
  
def GetEmailMatch(email):
  return re.match(r'([^@]+)@example\.com', email)

def GetUsername(email_address):
  match = GetEmailMatch(email_address)
  if match is None:
    return None
  return match.group(1)
```

But When I run **"pytype get_username.py",** I got an error.

> ninja: error: dependency cycle: /media/arpon/New -> /media/arpon/New

Can you suggest to me how can I overcome this error?

Comment: there are two functions defined and neither are called.... so where is this error from ?

Comment: this is a code snippet. pytype which is a static type analyzer for Python code, is supposed to extract types of that function from this code. I installed pytype as instructed in their official documentation. When I try to use that module to extract type using "pytype filename.py" I got an error which is provided before. It's from the pytype module I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The module usage is like this:

```py
from pytypes import typechecked

@typechecked
def some_function(a: int, b: str, c: List[Union[str, float]]) -> int:
    return a+len(b)+len(c)
```

So it looks like this module should be imported for `pytype` to work.

Interestingly, i just installed the same module to show you the example but it errors out because it works up to version `3.8` and i am using version `3.10`.

Can you confirm the version that you are using ?

Here are the official docs where i see this:
https://pypi.org/project/pytypes/

The error message is this:
`module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterable'`
and when searched the `collections` module that is referred to has changed beyong `3.8`.

Comment: Here is the official documentation of the module :
https://pypi.org/project/pytype/
https://google.github.io/pytype/user_guide.html

I am trying to use pytype, not pytypes. and my current Python version is Python 3.8.13.